# Push from Filbeat to Elasticsearch with custom _type and _id

Tags: filebeat

The problem is to push json logs collected by Filebeat to Elasticsearch with defined _type and _id. Default elastic _type is "log" and _id is smth. like "AVryuUKMKNQ7xhVUFxN2".

My log row:

```
 {"unit_id":10001,"node_id":1,"message":"Msg ..."}
```

Desired record in Elasticsearch:

```
"hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "filebeat",
    "_type" : "unit_id",
    "_id" : "10001",
    ...
    "_source" : {        
        "message" : "Msg ...",
        "node_id" : 1,
        ...
    }
} ]
```

I know how to do it with Logstash, just use document_id => "%{unit_id}" and document_type => "unit_id" in the output section. The goal is to use only Filebeat. Because it is a very-light weight solution and no intermediate aggregation is needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom `_type` by using the [`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_document_type) option in Filebeat.
There is no way to set the `_id` directly in Filebeat as of version 5.x.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths: ['/var/log/messages']
  document_type: syslog
```

You could use the Elasticsearch Ingest Node feature to set the `_id` field. You would need to use a [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html) to copy a value from the event into the `_id` field. Once you have defined your pipeline you would tell Filebeat to send its data to that pipeline using the [`output.elasticsearch.pipeline`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/elasticsearch-output.html#_pipeline_2) config option.

Comment: I find this very interesting and very baffling....the _bulk api makes it very simple to set the _id field to whatever you want, and Filebeat uses the native _bulk api to send the data over to es....why on earth isn't it a simple configuration setting then in Filebeat.yml to set it against a scheme just like the index pattern....ala { "index": { "index": [value from config], "_id": [also value from config]}}.  weird

Answer (score 1):

You can now set a custom _id : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-deduplication.html